# Not to pass ID in URL - UpdateApiView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to make update using my `API`. For that i am passing `id` in `URL` which is `pk`.

```
http://localhost:8000/api/manager/update/96
```

Where 96 is `primary key`. Now instead of passing `id` in url i want to pass `id` in body and update data. My url should look like this

```
http://localhost:8000/api/manager/update
```

Views.py

```
class ManagerUpdateAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwrgs):

        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)
        userprofile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=pk)

        serializer1 = EmployeeRegisterSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        serializer2 = EmployeeProfileSerializer(userprofile, data=request.data)

        user_role = ACLRoles.objects.get(id=4)

        if serializer1.is_valid() and serializer2.is_valid():

            serializer1.save()
            serializer2.save()

            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        print(serializer1.errors)
        print(serializer2.errors)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Serializers.py

```
class EmployeeProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [  
                    'user_employee_id',
                    'user_phone', 
                    'user_payroll_id',
                    'user_hire_date',
                    'user_pay_rate',
                    'user_salaried',
                    'user_excempt',
                    'user_groups',
                    'user_state',
                    'user_city',
                    'user_zipcode', 
                    'user_status',
                ]

class EmployeeRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # userprofile = EmployeeProfileSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name', 'email',]
```

How can i update data without passing `id` in url.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
class ManagerUpdateAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwrgs): #change is here
        pk = request.data['pk'] #change is here
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)
        userprofile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=pk)

        serializer1 = EmployeeRegisterSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        serializer2 = EmployeeProfileSerializer(userprofile, data=request.data)

        user_role = ACLRoles.objects.get(id=4)

        if serializer1.is_valid() and serializer2.is_valid():
            serializer1.save()
            serializer2.save()

            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        print(serializer1.errors)
        print(serializer2.errors)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

and provide **`pk`** in your POST payload as

```
{
    "pk":96,
    "other_data":"other data of your usual payload"
}
```

Comment: If i am not sending data one of the field it is giving error - `serializer2 {'salaried': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'excempt': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}`

Comment: you have to pass those data too in your message payload

Comment: I didn't understand which payload. I am passing `serializer2 = EmployeeProfileSerializer(userprofile, data=request.data)`

Comment: Payload is the data you are sending to drf

Comment: How can i pass it because `serializer1 = EmployeeRegisterSerializer(user, data=request.data)` is working even if i don't send any data it is perfectly updating my data. Just `serializer2` is not working

Comment: Please see this quest @JPG https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334275/update-using-apiview